# Take the difference of two corresponding chars in a char array

Tags: c++, char

I need to make a function that will take the difference of two corresponding chars, and then add them all up. So if s="3AB" and t="7C" I need to return ('3'-'7')+('A'-'C')+'B' Can't use any library functions. My current code leads to a memory error, I'm assuming because its going beyond the bounds of one of the arrays. How else could I terminate the loop though?

```
int difference(char s[], char t[]){
    int result = 0;
    int flag1 = 0;
    int flag2 = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(flag1 == 0 && flag2 == 0) {
        result += (s[i] - t[i]);
        if(s[i] == '\n') {
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        if(t[i] == '\n') {
            flag2 = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using the newline character (`\n`) as a terminator mark, whereas you (probably) should be using the `nul` character (`\0`), which C-strings use.

Comment: Also, you haven't specified **clearly** how to treat characters in the longer string when the two are of different lengths. In your example, you add the value of the character(s) in the first string, if that is longer, but what if the second is longer? You code doesn't handle these cases at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are going out out bounds, as your loop is not handing the case when both inputs have different lengths. When it reaches the end of the shorter string, it keeps going because of the longer string and tries to access characters that don't exist in the shorter string.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int difference(const char *s, const char *t) {
    int result = 0;
    while (*s != '\0' || *t != '\0') {
        if (*s != '\0') {
            if (*t != '\0') {
                result += (*s++ - *t++);
            }
            else {
                result += *s++;
            }
        } else {
            result += *t++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Of course, there are other ways you can write this, but then should get the point across.